# Create sigc::slot with no arguments

Tags: c++, signals, gtkmm

I'm trying to connect a timeout handler to my gtkmm code as shown in [gtkmm book](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-timeouts.html.en). However, my particular on_timeout() function doesn't need any arguments, and I'm struggling to properly create a `sigc::slot` object to pass to the `connect` function, as I encounter the following error (among others):

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(sigc::bound_mem_functor0<bool, DerivedWindow>)
```

and several

```
candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

referring to `sigc::bind`. How I am calling both functions:

```
_timeout_slot = sigc::bind(sigc::mem_fun(*this,&DerivedWindow::on_timeout));
_connection = Glib::signal_timeout().connect(_timeout_slot,timeout_value);
```

I'm doing this on a class `DerivedWindow` derived from `Gtk::Window`. What exactly am I doing wrong? Do I need to use `sigc::bind` and `sigc::mem_func` if I don't require any arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `sigc::bind` here since you are not binding any additional arguments to the slot (dealing with dereferencing the member function pointer for `this` is already taken care of by `sigc::mem_fun`). So, this is sufficient:

```
_timeout_slot = sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MyWindow::on_timeout)
_connection = Glib::signal_timeout().connect(_timeout_slot, timeout_value);
```

---

**A quick tip**: if you can use C++11, you can just pass lambdas as arguments to connect, which makes things more readable:

```
_connection = Glib::signal_timeout().connect([this]{ return on_timeout(); }, timeout_value);
```

For this to work, you may need to add

```
namespace sigc{
SIGC_FUNCTORS_DEDUCE_RESULT_TYPE_WITH_DECLTYPE
}
```

Also, if you want to connect to signals of a class instance (say a `Gtk::Button* btn`), you can make things even more compact by defining a macro

```
#define CONNECT(src, signal, ...) (src)->signal_##signal().connect(__VA_ARGS__)
```

which then allows you to write

```
CONNECT(btn, clicked, [this]{ btn_clicked_slot(); });
```